# Copying a range of cells to a specific area in another spreadhsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to copy a range of data to a new range in another spreadsheet. I am able to read the number of rows and columns that I need from the reference template but I am unable to copy the data to the new range, it just copies blanks.

```
function getTemplateName(){
  //Retrieves the template file and opens it to retrieve templates
  var getTemplateFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Evaluation Templates')
  while (getTemplateFile.hasNext())
  var openTemplates = getTemplateFile.next()
  var templateId = openTemplates.getId()
  var openSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateId)
  var listTemplates = openSpreadsheet.getSheets().valueOf()

  //pushes all sheets from evaluation templates to a new array to be referenced by the menu
  var templateArray = new Array()
  var templateNames = openSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i < templateNames.length ; i++) templateArray.push( [ templateNames[i].getName() ] )

  //Retrieves the template sheet tab by the name selected in the menu
  var getTemplateSheet = openSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Shoulder')
  var getObjectiveData = getTemplateSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  Logger.log(getObjectiveData)
  //Counts the rows in the template sheet
  var countRows = getTemplateSheet.getMaxRows()
  var countColumns = getTemplateSheet.getMaxColumns()
  Logger.log(countRows)
  Logger.log(countColumns)
  //Gets row number of 'Objective' 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Evaluation')
  var objectiveLine = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  for (var i = 0; i < objectiveLine.length; i++){
  if (objectiveLine[i][0] == 'Objective'){
      //inserts the number of rows 
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(i+1, countRows)

  //copies template data to new active row
  var newdata = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 1, countRows, 
  countColumns).setValues(getObjectiveData)
```

Edit: changed above code to be .set Values with empty cells still being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your range `(i, 1, countRows, countColumns)` is likely more than 1 cell big, but with `setValue()` you assign to each cell of this range only the first value of the value range `getObjectiveData`.
- If the first value of `getObjectiveData` is empty - than you assign a range of empty data.

### For assigning to a 2D range a 2D value range, you need to use the method [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) instead of `getValue()`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I did try .setvalues and the cells stayed empty.

Comment: In this case please provide a copy of  your spreadsheet to understand where the problem comes from - it is hard to troubleshoot without seeing the data.

Comment: I managed to get the code to work by getting the A1 notation of the data range then using getRange of that A1 notation.